# XAMP Apache - load a spercific site in localhost

Tags: apache, localhost

I am using XAMP on Windows and I am interested to set the default localhost to a specific site.

I have a number of sites set up in virtual hosts. What do I have to do to to make this one open as localhost and not only ng-objects.dev?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "F:\ngobjects"
  ServerName ng-objects.dev
  ServerAlias  www.ng-objects.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

Currently my http://localhost/ home doesn't open anything, I get

Object not found!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using Name-based Virtual hosting. And so if there is no `<VirtualHost>` section that specifically matches your request then the first `<VirtualHost>` section will be used ([refer this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html)).

And so if the http://localhost request should load contents from "F:\ngobjects" then that section has to be placed at top of all other `<VirtualHost>` sections.

Comment: Yes that was that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, `http://localhost` loads apache default page. But looks like it's not set in your scenario.Locate your [host file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29#Location_in_the_file_system) and put below on a new line.
`127.0.0.1    localhost`
`127.0.0.1    ng-objects.dev`
`127.0.0.1    www.ng-objects.dev`.
 Also, you will need to add [ServerAlias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#serveralias) for localhost.
`ServerAlias localhost`